# Looking for a desktop application similar to jsFiddle

Tags: html, css, javascript, tools

Is there a desktop application or IDE for Windows or GNU/Linux similar to *jsFiddle* where I can insert my JavaScript code, HTML and CSS and see how it executes?

I don't mind writing HTML, CSS and JavaScript in the places they are supposed to be, but what I don't want is the process of

*Save changes

Open browser

Refresh

Edit

Save

Open Browser*
...

Comment: What desktop platform do you use? It would be helpful if this information was in the question.

Comment: Windows or GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a 'jsFiddle for the desktop', but there are [several ways to force your browser to refresh](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/quick-tip-4-ways-to-auto-refresh-your-browser-when-designing-new-sites/) when you save a file or at a set interval.

One advantage of choosing this route is that you can use your existing editor in half of your screen, put a browser window in the other half, and watch the live preview update as you code. Having a wide monitor helps too.